# is it a good idea to exec start rmiregistry in RMI server?

Tags: java, ipc, rmi, interprocess

is it a good idea to put `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("start rmiregistry");` in RMI server to automatically start the rmiregistry? Or you guys got other suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to try something like this:

```
  try {
         java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
         System.out.println("RMI registry ready.");
      } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("Exception starting RMI registry:");
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

Taken from [here](http://home.tiscali.nl/bmc88/java/sbook/051.html). Documentation available [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/rmi/registry/LocateRegistry.html).